# How do I define this simple views relationship?

Tags: 7, views

- I have a `person` table that has a primary key `id`. This is a base table.
- I have an `address` table that has a foreign key `person_id`. This is NOT a base table (has no primary key)
- The address table contains a `person`'s address, but not every `person` has an `address`.

[image]

When describing these two tables to views, how do I set it up so that when the `person` table is used as a base table, I can optionally add a relationship to `address` to join in the information?

I know I can add an **implicit join** on the `address` definition like so:

```
$data['address']['table']['join'] = array(
  'person' => array(
    'field' => 'person_id',
    'left_field' => 'id',
  ),
);
```

This allows me to add any `address` fields automatically in the Views UI. Views would by default use a `LEFT JOIN` to bring in the `address` data. I can change this to an `INNER JOIN` in the above definition, but **I want to allow the user to chose**, which is exactly what using a relationship handler does (has the "require this relationship checkbox", which controls `INNER` vs `LEFT`).

However, in my analysis of how these handlers work, I don't think I can define the handler in a way that this will work. It seems the relationship handler should be added to *the foreign key on the base table*. My base table is `person`, which does not have the foreign key.

For instance, I tried this:

```
$data['address']['person_id']['relationship'] = array(
  'base' => 'person',
  'base field' => 'id',
  'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
  'label' => t('Address'),
  'help' => t("Has basic information on a person's address.")
);
```

But this doesn't work, since `address` is not used as a base table in my View.

How can I do this?

**P.S.** part of my confusion/trouble stem from my inability to define a table [neither as a base table nor an implicit join table](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/97604/views-define-table-without-describing-it-as-a-base-or-join-table), which is what I want to do for `address`.

**UPDATE 1**: For a real-world example, look at the table `accesslog` and how it relates to `users`. When working with a view w/ `users` base table, you cannot explicitly add the `accesslog` relationship, but you can add all the `accesslog` fields since `statistics.views.inc` creates the implicit relationship. My schema is similar, but I want to use explicit relationships instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first point is that, the table itself should be defined in order for Views to access it. It's not necessary to define all the fields in the table; just define what you want to access.

You can however, define additional fields that are not in the table. The ***default*** convention in the `$data` array is the `table name => column_name` but you still can add non-existing keys to the array without Views looking for that field in the query.

Try this:

```
<?php 

$data['person']['addresses'] = array(
  'title' => 'Addresses',
  'help' => 'Load persons address information',
  'relationship' => array(
     'title' => t('Person\'s address'),
     'base' => 'address', // base table
     'base field' => 'person_id',
     'relationship field' => 'id',
     'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
     'label' => t('Address information'),
     'help' => t('Address information'),
  ),
);
```

You will now see a new relationship, Address, to join the table, along with a checkbox to make it an `INNER` instead of a default `LEFT` join.

Similarly, you can add additional fields, arguments and filters without having a real field with the array's key in the table.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to take your suggestion and modify it so it works properly. I will edit your code sample to reflect that.